# Xcode Project with shared CoreData for iOS & MacOS Targets

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

A few months ago I started to work on a MacOS Application which required CoreData implementation. Today I am beginning to work on a related iOS application that is based on the same Api, and though relies on the same model. I added my iOS target on my project and I mutualised some classes (by adding them to both targets), including the CoreData Stack:

1. I added my `app.xcdatamodeld` on both targets
2. I added my `Object+CoreDataClass.swift` & `Object+CoreDataProperties.swift` on both targets

[image]

3. I modified my `ManagedObjectsController` to support both iOS and MacOS implementation

[image]

by defining the `appDelegate` for both iOS and OSX, I can access it the same way to get my context `let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext`

It works fine but **I was wondering if I am doing this right**. Is this the correct way to mutualise access to appDelegate instances between two targets?

Should I use some kind of Protocole & Generic Typing?

Or should I simply build a ManagedObjectController for each target?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring a protocol helps if you have multiple classes which you want to both support common functions.  But in this case, *UIApplication* and *NSApplication* already support the common functions you need!  The problem is that you need access two different global symbols.

One alternative worth considering is: Instead of declaring two classes *IosAppDelegate* and *MacAppDelegate*, declare a single class *AppDelegate*, and move that dirty `#if` code out of your *ManagedObjectsController* class and into *AppDelegate*.  Then, this *AppDelegate* could be used wherever you need a reference to the shared app delegate.  This is more than a few places in most projects.

But if you want to get your product out the door asap, and this *ManagedObjectsController* is the only place you need the shared app delegate, your code is fine.

Comment: Alright thanks for the clarification. When you say "ove that dirty #if into AppDelegate", do you mean an `Appdelegate.swift` file with a big `#if` defining a `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate` and an `#elseif` defining `class MacAppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate` ? 
Won't that be more confusing?

Comment: Or do you mean that I should keep MacAppDelegate and IosAppDelegate, but create a third singleton class `AppDelegate`, and put the `if` arround a `shared` variable?

Comment: I meant what you said in your first comment, but what you said in your second comment would also work, as will your original code.  Getting back to your original question, there is **no right way** to do this.  Keep in mind what economist Thomas Sowell has said about public policy options: *There are no solutions.  There are only trade-offs.*  That also applies to engineering design decisions.  In this case, all of the three options we discussed will work.  Maybe there is not much difference among their (benefits minus costs).  If that is the case, just move on with what you've already got.